# Combining enumeration and boxes in exam package

Tags: enumerate, exam

I am using the `exam` package for a multiple choice exam and would like to tweak the style format of the multiple choices with boxes. Right now I am using this setup for square checkboxes:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\checkboxchar{$\Box$}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
The question?
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice
This
\choice
That
\choice
And some more
\end{checkboxes}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This results in an output similar to this:

1. The question?

   □ This

   □ That

   □ And some more

However, I would like to customize this a little more.

1. Is it possible to include the enumeration in each line of choices, e.g. »□ This« becomes »□ a.) This«, »□ That« becomes »□ b.) That« and »□ And some more« becomes »□ c.) And some more«?
2. Is it possible to use an image as checkbox? I would prefer a square box that is much larger, i.e. spanning two or more lines, and has some rounded corners.
3. If a larger box or image is chosen, its bottomline is currently aligned with the baseline of the first line of the answer text. You can see this by changing `\checkboxchar{$\Box$}` in the MWE into `\checkboxchar{\Huge$\Box$}`. Can I alter the vertical positioning of the box somehow?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: With the eforms package you could use PDF checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to you question(s) is yes.

I used TikZ in order to get the rounded corners, so I also used the `baseline` option of tikz to adjust the height.  Otherwise I could use `\raisebox`.

While `oneparcheckboxes` uses the `choice` counter, `checkboxes` does not.

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\checkboxeshook{\setcounter{choice}{0}}
\checkboxchar{\tikz[baseline=(base)]{\draw[thick,rounded corners=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (1em,1em);
  \coordinate (base) at (0pt,0.5em-0.5\ht\strutbox+0.5\dp\strutbox);}
  \stepcounter{choice}\alph{choice}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
The question?
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice
This
\choice
That
\choice
And some more
\end{checkboxes}
\question
The question?
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice
This
\choice
That
\choice
And some more
\end{checkboxes}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick :)